# Split column with tidyr with different lenghts

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to separate a column with tidyr to extract the grade level. The Column looks like this:

```
School.Name
School A ES
SchoolB MS
```

The is no standard way the schools are named, so when I use separate

```
separate(DF, School.Name,c("School.Name","Number","Grade Level")
```

I get this

```
School.Name  Number   Grade Level
School           A         ES
SchoolB         MS         NA
```

Is there a way to tell tidyr to read from the right rather that from the left

Comment: @HubertL- Sorry meant from right to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `?separate`:

```
separate(DF, School.name, c("School.Name","Number","Grade Level"), fill = "left")
```

Then you got result like :

```
  School.Name  Number Grade Level
1      school       A          ES
2        <NA> schoolB          MS
```

**EDIT:**

parameter `fill` controls when separated characters size doesn't match column size, optional `warn, right, left.`

1. Case 1: separated characters size `<` column size

e.g.

```
"schoolB MS" to C("A", "B", "C"), fill = "left" : <NA> schoolB MS


"schoolB MS" to C("A", "B", "C"), fill = "right" : schoolB MS <NA>
```

2. Case 2: separated characters size `>` column size

e.g.

```
"schoolB MS" to C("A"), fill = "warn" : schoolB #default drop extra from the right
```